# Avoid grid from overlaping itself when transforming scale

Tags: html, css

**Problem:** [play.code-it.net](http://play.code-it.net)

I have this grid which I set to transform the scale to 1.25 when hovering. The problem is that, when an element 'gets transformed', it overlaps the elements next to it.

How could I fix that?

**CSS:** (the grid is the class .games and all the grid elements are in the class .game) [code-it.net/custom/css/jogos.css](http://code-it.net/custom/css/jogos.css)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="games">     
    <a onclick="gameWindow(640, 400, 960); selectedGame='pong';">
        <div id="pong" class="game" search="pong" style="transition: all .1s ease-in-out;"></div></a>

    <a onclick="gameWindow(640, 400, 960); selectedGame='dama';">
        <div id="dama" class="game" search="dama" style="transition: all .1s ease-in-out;"></div></a>

    <a onclick="gameWindow(640, 400, 960); selectedGame='forca';">
        <div id="forca" class="game" search="forca" style="transition: all .1s ease-in-out;" ></div></a>

    <a onclick="gameWindow(640, 400, 960); selectedGame='pacman';">
        <div id="pacman" class="game" search="pacman" style="transition: all .1s ease-in-out;"></div></a>

    <a onclick="gameWindow(640, 400, 960); selectedGame='math';">
        <div id="quick-math" class="game" search="quick math" style="transition: all .1s ease-in-out;"></div></a>

    <a onclick="gameWindow(640, 400, 960); selectedGame='fut-mesa';">
        <div id="fut-mesa" class="game" search="futebol de mesa" style="transition: all .1s ease-in-out;"></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Push the neighbors out of the way?

Comment: @helb It would be a great solution

Comment: That's what transforms actually do, they are **purely visual** and do not affect actual layout. You would need javascript for this.

Comment: Or to set them as `position:relative` and modify their dimensions instead of using transform